# how to figure out if process is really running or waiting to run on Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

This is purely academic question, I don't really need to know this information for anything, but I would like to understand kernel a bit more :-)

According to kernel documentation http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html processes in linux kernel have following states:

> #### Running
>
> The process is either running (it is the current process in the
> system) or it is ready to run (it is waiting to be assigned to one of
> the system's CPUs).
>
> #### Waiting
>
> The process is waiting for an event or for a resource. Linux
> differentiates between two types of waiting process; interruptible and
> uninterruptible. Interruptible waiting processes can be interrupted by
> signals whereas uninterruptible waiting processes are waiting directly
> on hardware conditions and cannot be interrupted under any
> circumstances.
>
> #### Stopped
>
> The process has been stopped, usually by receiving a signal. A process
> that is being debugged can be in a stopped state.
>
> #### Zombie
>
> This is a halted process which, for some reason, still has a
> task_struct data structure in the task vector. It is what it sounds
> like, a dead process.

As you can see, when I take a snapshot of processes state, using command like `ps`, I can see, if it's in `Running` state, that process either was literally Running or just waiting to be assigned to some CPU by kernel.

In my opinion, these 2 states (that are actually both represented by 1 state in `task_struct`) are quite different.

Why there is no state like "Ready" that would mean the process is "ready to run" but wasn't assigned to any CPU so far, so that the `task_struct` would be more clear about the real state? Is it even possible to retrieve this information, or is it secret for whatever reason which process is "literally running" on the CPU?

Comment: I don't think it's secret information since the scheduler would need to know what to switch in and out. The best way to find an answer to this would probably be to sign up to a Kernel mailing list or to look at [the source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h) yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct task_struct contains a long to represent current state:

```
volatile long state;          /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
```

This simply indicates if a process is 'runnable'.

To see the currently executing process you should look at the runqueue. Specifically a struct rq (as defined in kernel/sched/sched.h) contains:

```
struct task_struct *curr, *idle, *stop;
```

The pointer *curr is the currently running process on this runqueue (there exists a runqueue per CPU).

You should consult files under kernel/sched/ to see how the Kernel determines which processes should be scheduled according to the different scheduling algorithms if you are interested in exactly how it arrives at the running state.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a linux-kernel answer but a more general about scheduling ^^
A core part of any OS is the Scheduler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_scheduler

Many of them work giving every process a time slice of execution and letting each of them do a little bit of work before switching (referred as a context switch) to another process.

Since the length of a time slice is in the order of milliseconds by the time the information you requested is shown, the state has surely changed so differentiate between "Really Running" and "Ready-but-not-really-running" could result (most of the time) in inaccurate informations.